# scrapy export the data to files by urls'path

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

How can I change the scrapy's sorce code , in orde to save files by the urls, when I export the data from HTML pages.

For example:
this pages (`http://example/big/ppp`) have lots of pages links

1. `http://example/big/ppp/a`
2. `http://example/big/ppp/b`
3. `http://example/big/ppp/c`
4. ......

and I wnat to save the data from

`http://example/big/ppp/a` **in** *d:/ppp/a.csv*

`http://example/big/ppp/b` **in** *d:/ppp/b.csv*

`http://example/big/ppp/c` **in** *d:/ppp/c.csv*

because of this pages(`http://example/big/ppp`) have lots of links that like 
`http://example/big/ppp/a`,`http://example/big/ppp/b`.

So could you help me, kind person!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scrapy pipeline to do this job, add a field to the item you are going to export, for example named 'source' (`http://example/big/ppp/a`) to record where the item from:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter

class MyCsvPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.csvfiles = {}
        self.exporter = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        for e in self.exporter.values():
            e.finish_exporting()
        for f in self.csvfiles.values():
            f.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        csv = item['source'].split('/')[-1] + '.csv'
        if csv not in self.csvfiles:
            newfile = open('d:/ppp/'+csv, 'wb')
            self.csvfiles[csv] = newfile
            self.exporter[csv] = CsvItemExporter(newfile)
            self.exporter[csv].start_exporting()
        self.exporter[csv].export_item(item)

        return item
```

apply this pipeline in settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'xxxx.pipelines.MyCsvPipeline': 300,
}
```

another option
use `scrapy crawl xxx -t csv -o all.csv --loglevel=INFO` to export all items to a csv, then use another script to separate it into small csv according to 'source'.